# Get specific line from command output in awk

Tags: shell, awk, pipe

I have used pipeline to read specific record from impala shell. Here is what I got

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ echo "select * from abc where key > 'a-26052014015400' limit 1;" | impala-shell
Starting Impala Shell without Kerberos authentication
Connected to localhost.localdomain:21000
Server version: impalad version cdh5-1.3.0 RELEASE (build 40e1b62cf0b97f666d084d9509bf9639c575068c)
Welcome to the Impala shell. Press TAB twice to see a list of available commands.

Copyright (c) 2012 Cloudera, Inc. All rights reserved.

(Shell build version: Impala Shell vcdh5-1.3.0 (40e1b62) built on Tue Mar 25 13:46:44 PDT 2014)
Query: select * from abc where key > 'a-26052014015400' limit 1
[localhost.localdomain:21000] > +------------------------+------+----------------+-------+
| key                    | hpid | uts            | value |
+------------------------+------+----------------+-------+
| a-26052014015700 | HS2  | 26052014015450 | 50    |
+------------------------+------+----------------+-------+
Returned 1 row(s) in 2.42s
Goodbye
```

What I really want is  `a-26052014015700 | HS2  | 26052014015450 | 50` this record in awk programming. I have tried with pipelined awk command

```
`echo "select * from abc where key > 'a-26052014015400' limit 1;" | impala-shell| awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | awk -F '>' '{print $1}`
```

but didn't get the expected output. Any better and efficient method to extract the record?

Comment: Won't `grep` be a better tool if you just want to extract the pattern?

Comment: @unxnut thanks for your comment and  am not stick to awk and pipe command,just want to get this record only.

Comment: In that case, your best bet is to create a regular expression to describe some pattern in your record (key value, perhaps) and use `grep` to filter that.

Comment: Why are you using `=` and `>` as your field separator? I don't see them in the table output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to pipe it to `grep`:

```
$  grep -E "| a-[0-9]* | HS2  | [0-9]* | [0-9]* |"
```

to get rid of the first `|` and the last `|`:

```
$  grep -Eo "  a-[0-9]* \| HS2 \| [0-9]* \| [0-9]* "
```

"-E" to access the extended regular expression syntax

"-o" is used to only output the matching segment of the line, rather than the full contents of the line.

Comment: You need some `*` or `+` quantifiers in your regexp, don't you?

Comment: @Networker thanks for your answer I have used it with slide change

 grep -Eo " a-[0-9]* \| HS2  \| [0-9]* \| [0-9]* " because in contains 2012 as well which is not required.

Answer (score 3):

If you know your output will always be in a format of *X* lines of header and *Y* lines of footer, you can use `head` and `tail` to get only the part you need,

```
    echo query | impala-shell | tail -n +X | head -n -Y

    # -- in your case above --
    echo "select * from abc where key > 'a-26052014015400' limit 1;" | impala-shell \
                | tail -n +13 | head -n -3 

    # returns
    | a-26052014015700 | HS2  | 26052014015450 | 50    |
```

---

**tail**

```
    -n, --lines=K
            output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; 
            or use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth
```

**head**

```
    -n, --lines=[-]K
            print the first K lines instead of the first 10; 
            with the leading '-', print all but the last K lines of each file
```

Comment: You don’t even need to know how many lines come after the one(s) you’re looking for. To capture the 14th line, all you need is `| tail -n +13 | head -n 1`. (On some systems, the archaic, undocumented `… | head -1` syntax might work.) To get the 14th-16th lines, use `| tail -n +13 | head -n 3`.